# BlackBerry - Unable to get a file with REM extension

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

As part of the application, we are creating a file myApp.cfg in "file:///store/home/user/" location on the device. I have enabled encryption (Option| Security | Encryption | Encrypt). However, the file is not getting encrypted. I dont see a file myApp.cfg.rem. This is happening in the client environment though. What am I missing?

Thanks
Krish