# BlackBerry 9900 - Encryption and file losses

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have enabled encryption on the 9900 device(Options->Security->Encryption->Encrypt). My application(BlackBerry OS 7.0 compatiable) creates a .CFG file at this "/Device/home/user/ark.cfg"  location in device memory.  Due to encryption this file is renamed to .CFG.REM, which i understand. However there are certain scenarios in which this file is removed/deleted. I am pretty sure that this is not done by the application itself. Are there any other circumstances in which the file could be lost? For example some IT policy settings in the BES.

Thanks
KrishIndia

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381352/blackberry-unable-to-get-a-file-with-rem-extension

Comment: That also posted by myself, but there also no reply